# How to set the default user as the current user object in django?

Tags: python, django

I have created a mini project called **ToDoList App**. I have used **class based views** for create, update and delete functions. There is MyTasks icon on navbar.

**What do I want?**
I want to set the default user as the current logged in user. Tasks of one person should not be seen by any another person.

I have tried all the solutions but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code in models.py file:

```
class MyTasks(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="mytasks")
    task_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="ID")
    task_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="", help_text="The title of the task", verbose_name="Task Title", blank=False)
    task_desc = models.TextField(default="", help_text="The description of task", verbose_name="Task Description", blank=False)
    task_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(), verbose_name="Task Date & Time")
    task_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Task Completed")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = User
        super(MyTasks, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_title
```

Here is my code in views.py file:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f"{username.capitalize()}, you have successfully created an account")
            return redirect("home")
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context={'form':form})

class TaskCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    """View to create new task."""
    model = MyTasks
    context_object_name = 'task'
    template_name = 'task_create.html'
    raise_exception = True
    success_message = 'Task successfully created!'
    fields = ['task_title', 'task_desc', 'task_time']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('task_list')
```

When I used the **save method** to achieve the task, it is showing this error:

> ValueError: Cannot assign "<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>"

Please help me to achieve this task. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to override the create view, and set the user there. Can you add your view and serializer?

Comment: Yes I have added a portion of views.py file.

Comment: Just posted an answer, can you try that?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it.When I am saving the task, after clicking on save button, it is showing me this error. - The view myapp.views.TaskCreateView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: I edited the code. Now that we call the super function, it'll call the HttpResponseRedirect which will navigate to the success_url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the user upon form validation. Don't forget to remove the `save` function on your model. That's not going to work.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView


class TaskCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    """View to create new task."""
    model = MyTasks
    context_object_name = 'task'
    template_name = 'task_create.html'
    raise_exception = True
    success_message = 'Task successfully created!'
    fields = ['task_title', 'task_desc', 'task_time']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('task_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score -1):

- In your view. If user is logged in, you can use

  ```
  request.user
  ```

  If you show me your view I can help you more with this.

  ... And change user attribute in your MyTask class to

  ```
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="mytasks")
  ```

  then set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py` to

  `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app-where-is-user-model.model-name'`

-use dot notation for that string.